# extract features for names,location,organization and place for named entity recignition

Tags: database, information-retrieval

I am trying to work on annotationg the entities in twitter datasets mainly, name, organization, location and place. I am trying to generate a feature set for this purpose. Any recommenadations on where and how can I get a list or database of all such entities so that I can use those to annotate the entities.

Answer (score 1):

You could try DBPedia or YAGO. The YAGO ontology is pretty huge you might want to extract the details you want from it.